# print out hashmap collision

Tags: java, hashmap

Is there anyway I can print out the Keys with the values that had collisions ? If a key has two values I want to be able to print out those values how can I do that I am inside the hash map class and making modification to it.

Comment: *(I think you're talking about hashes collisions and the value of the hashes colliding and **not** about the 'value' as in {key,value} pairs, am I correct?)*...  If for whatever reason you have too many collisions it may be due to a poorly choosen *hashCode* method: if you have different non-equals object returning the same hash (it's bad, but it is not forbidden), then you may degrade the performance of the Map.  Instead of modificating the code of various Map implementations, you may instead want to write a better *hashCode* method for your non-equals objects prone to hashes collision...

Comment: @user988052 I agree, even as I answered below, just call hashcode and see what is the problem with hashcode...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If a key has two values...

In a `HashMap`, a key cannot have two values. If you call `map.put(key,value)` with an existing `key`, the old value is removed from the map, and is returned by `put()`.

One way to have multiple values per key is by using `HashMap<K,Collection<V>>`. This automatically provides the functionality you want, since you can simply examine the contents of the value collection after you've added the new element to it.

There are also third-party classes that provide this functionality, such as [`MultiValueMap`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiValueMap.html).

**edit:**

If you're talking about multiple keys ending up in the same **bucket**, then you need to modify `HashMap`'s `put()` method:

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null)
        return putForNullKey(value);
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
    if (table[i] != null) {
        // TODO: there's already something in this bucket
    }
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        ...
```

(Add your code where the `TODO` line is.)

You'll need to make similar changes to `putForNullKey()` and other related methods, such as `putForCreate()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're modifying the HashMap class then you should be able to find where the list of elements is chained off the hash array and detect when there's more than one in the chain.

HOWEVER, you'd better have a very good reason for modifying HashMap, AND you'd better change the package and name of the class (to something like com.my.company.HashMapWithCollisionStatistics) or risk the eternal wrath of everybody who comes behind you to maintain Java code in your group.

Comment: LOL. Yeah I did. "What goes around comes around" wouldn't want someone to do that to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just use MultiMap from google collections.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to do that? If just want to check the collision then call hashcode() on the objects that you are trying to store in the hashmap without storing them.